# How to translate upwards

Tags: android, translate-animation

I want to create a translate animation in relation to other objects on the screen

```
    if(vipUpSet == null) {
    Rect contactUsLocation = new Rect();
    Rect infoLocation = new Rect();
    Rect vipLocation = new Rect();
    contactUs.getGlobalVisibleRect(contactUsLocation);
    info.getGlobalVisibleRect(infoLocation);
    vip.getGlobalVisibleRect(vipLocation);
    vipUp = new TranslateAnimation(vipLocation.left, contactUsLocation.right + 20, vipLocation.top, contactUsLocation.top);
    vipUpSet = new AnimationSet(true);
    vipUpSet.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    vipUpSet.addAnimation(scaleDown);
    vipUpSet.addAnimation(vipUp);
    vipUpSet.setDuration(1000);
    vipUpSet.setFillAfter(true);
    }
```

[image]

I have two buttons at the top of the screen called contactUs and info

I want vip to take off from where it is, and be to the right side of the contactUs button

the current setup, makes the view disappear and fly in from the bottom, I want it to fly from its current state.

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

- You are using the wrong deltas.

This should do:

```
float deltaY = contactUsLocation.top - vipLocation.top;
vipUp = new TranslateAnimation(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, deltaY);
// ... same ...
```

This code will shift contactUs from its current position up to where it is aligned horizontally with vip (but no horizontal translation).

The initial deltas set to `0.f` mean the `View` starts animating from its current position. The final deltas are the offsets of the translation.

Be also careful that the `scaleDown` animation don't interfere with the translation.